# Material preview mode transparency (Blender 2.8 Eevee)

Tags: materials, 3d-view, transparency, eevee-render-engine

I am in the material preview mode in Blender 2.8, using Eevee renderer. What material settings do I need to set, to get a transparent object in the viewport? The use-case is when modelling an object with reference side/front/top images - I'd like to be able to see the image behind the object that I'm modelling. Otherwise, the image is covered by the mesh that I'm working on.

Comment: Then I cannot see the images on the reference planes (as they are applied as materials). Or is there a setting to do it?

Answer (score 5):

**Solution 01**
Add a reference image

Blender can add *Reference images*, that are visible in the 3D viewport, but not in renders.
They're great choice for modelling, and have many options available.
*Add > Image > Reference*
[image]

**Solution 02**
Enable transparency in Eevee

To make a material appear transparent in Material preview, use the Alpha value.
Don't forget to set Blend mode to *Alpha-blend*.
(If you cannot find these settings, switch to Eevee render engine in the render tab)

[image]